# INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE vs TRUNCATE/INSERT

Tags: mysql, database

I'm currently rewriting a data push script that pulls data out of a MSSQL database on another server and then inserts the data into a MySQL database. This process is cron'ed to run nightly and is handled via PHP.

The original script [`TRUNCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html)s the tables and reinserts all the data nightly. Some of the tables have primary, unique keys that come from the MSSQL database. Some of the tables do not.

I am considering adding generic primary keys to the MySQL tables that do not currently have them so I may do a [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) instead of emptying the tables and reinserting the data each night. The primary keys would be used for no other reason then this process.

Would the process be faster/less resource intensive if I did an [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) versus the [`TRUNCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) and then `INSERT` as the script currently does? Is it worth the hassle of creating generic primary keys on the tables that currently do not have them just to do an [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)? I am looking for the best possible performance out of this script.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give a general answer without knowing the specifics of your data.  I would want to know the size of the tables in rows, and if you are using Innodb.  However, if the tables are small <1000 rows, and/or not using Innodb, I would just leave as-is.  However, if you have large tables, I have seen dramatic improvements in speed using the INSERT..ON DUPLICATE method.

A good process may be to switch over one or two of the larger tables and measure your speed improvements.  If worthwhile, then proceed with the rest.